# Creating a UTF-8 string from hexadecimal code

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, hex, codepoint

In C++, it's possible create a UTF-8 string using this kind of notation: `"\uD840\uDC50"`.

However this doesn't work in PHP. Is there a similar notation?

If not, is there any built-in way to create a UTF-8 string knowing its Unicode code point?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've ended up implementing it like this:

```
$utf8 = html_entity_decode("&#x4E00;", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: use ENT_QUOTES | ENT_COMPAT  to convert quotes as well

Comment: This has limitations and will not work with all UTF-8 chars, as not all hex chars are suported in HTML standard. See https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm ("not defined in HTML 4 standard")

Answer (score 2):

```
function hexToString($str){return chr(hexdec(substr($str, 2)));}
$result = preg_replace_callback("/(\\\\x..)/isU", function($m) { return hexToString($m[0] ); }, $str);
```