# encoding error displaying fontawesome with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, font-awesome

i'm trying to use fontawesome with imagemagick to display it's character as png ,
here is my code:

```
$size = '50';
$text = '&#xf03c;';
$imgW = 200;
$imgH = 200;
$font = 'fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setResolution(144,144);
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont($font);
$draw->setFontSize($size);
//$draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
//$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
//$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$image->newImage($imgW, $imgH, new ImagickPixel('none'));
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $text);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

but the image output looks like this
[image: coded image]

any idea how to fix such a encoding problem?

Comment: Is the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` in the same directory?

Comment: for sure cause if not in the same dir or dir is not valid it will through an exception rather than rendering the image

Answer (score 2):

Using the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098764/creating-a-utf-8-string-from-hexadecimal-code) to ensure I had a UTF-8 string being passed into ImageMagick works for me. The only change from your code is the second line:

```
$size = '50';
$text = html_entity_decode("&#xf004;", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$imgW = 200;
$imgH = 200;
$font = 'fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setResolution(144,144);
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont($font);
$draw->setFontSize($size);
//$draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
//$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
//$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$image->newImage($imgW, $imgH, new ImagickPixel('none'));
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, $text);
$image->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Unicode sequence isn't being recognised properly as you are getting multiple characters rather than just one. If you get one missing block displaying - it's a font issue!

I have a unicode escape working in Ruby RMagic so maybe the same sequence will work for you in PHP?

On http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ the "fa-heart" is listed as "#xf004;"
This appears to be an HTML escape, so the one you need should be:

```
$text = "\uf004";
```

Comment: Have you also set the PHP script to run in UTF-8 mode? mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); // More info on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: Set both character sets to UTF-8. mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); and use $draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');

Comment: I've tried that but does not work as well , this problem is about how imagemagick read unicode and have no relation to php cause if i use another library such as GD it render icons without any problems